# изменить расположение маркера у <ul>

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу стилизовать маркер

```
li::marker {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

отвечает за его размер и центрирует относительно размера текста, но как изменить расположение?

Comment: если у вас маркер с абсолютным позиционированием, то в чем проблема менять расположение?

Comment: Можно сместить текст по горизонтали со знаком минус тоже работает `li{  text-indent: 50px; }`..

Comment: The position: static property prevents left from having an effect.
я не понимаю что и куда прописывать

Comment: https://webref.ru/css/list-style-position еще можно поиграться с `direction: [ rtl || ltr ]` если нужна бОльшая гибкость, используйте полноценный псевдо-элемент - `:before` или `:after`, а про маркер забудьте...